# Comparing two randomly loaded dice

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, dirichlet-distribution

Say I have two six-sided dice, A and B, which are loaded in different ways, and I'd like to compare their probability distributions.

So far I've constructed the priors for the probabilities $\vec\pi = (\pi_1,...,\pi_6)$ for both dice as a Dirichlet distribution, with $\vec\alpha=(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ in both. If I roll each die N times, I know that the outcome $\vec x=(x_1,...,x_6)$ will follow a multinomial distribution, and I can get the posteriors for $\vec\pi$ as $Dir(\vec\alpha + \vec{x})$.

My question is how I would go about comparing $Pr(x=i|A)$ against $Pr(x=i|B)$. My understanding is that I can treat each $\pi_{i}$ as a variable from a Beta distribution $Beta(x_i, N-x_i)$, and compare these distributions. Is this correct?

Comment: I would have guessed without checking that it was $\text{Beta}(a_i+x_i, \sum a_j - a_i +N-x_i)$.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_distributions) suggests much the same thing for marginal distributions

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks.